# dismissWithClickedButtonIndex not works in UIViewController - UIScrollView - ActionSheet relation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I hope you can help me with the next case.

**Description:**

I have a class that "creates" a dynamic form programmatically, this class inherits from UIViewController and is called "DinamicScreen".

```
@interface DinamicScreen : UIViewController ...
```

I have a ViewController (connected to a viewController storyboard), which inherits from "DinamicScreen".

```
@interface MandatoryInformationViewController : DinamicScreen<UIPickerViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
```

In "DinamicScreen" I'm only painting the UIView, but all delegates are passed to the context.

```
uiTextField = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:....
// Context is "MandatoryInformationViewController" in this case
[uiTextField setDelegate:context];
```

The form implements a UIScrollView containing UILabels and UITextFields. An UITextField can open an ActionSheet showing an UIPickerView and two buttons (OK, Cancel).

```
DinamicScreenScrollView *uiScrollView = [[DinamicScreenScrollView alloc]initWithFrame...
[uiScrollView addSubview:uiTextField];....
```

**The problem:**

When I click on a "pickerTextField" the ActionSheet appears without problems, but when I click OK or Cancel, it crashes (I think it is the ActionSheet).

When I did a debug, I observed that the flow does not run correctly

```
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

The snapshot http://s29.postimg.org/8zxkj333b/Captura_de_pantalla_2013_12_17_a_la_s_17_45_38.png

If I do not implement the UIScrollView it works perfectly, but its a must for it to be implemented.

If more information is needed please let me know, it's my first question on StackOverflow

Excuse me for my English, I'm working on it.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact error message when it crashes?  When you were debugging, did you identify what line it crashes on?

Comment: No error, only the application freezes, but continue runtime, just here http://s29.postimg.org/8zxkj333b/Captura_de_pantalla_2013_12_17_a_la_s_17_45_38.png

Answer (score 0):

Well, after three days to fix it.

The problem was that were painting in the view of "MandatoryViewController" instead of "DinamicScreen", I changed that and voila.

```
[[context view] addSubview:uiScrollView]; // [wrong]
[[self view] addSubview:uiScrollView];    // [well]
```

I supposed that this post are a documentation now.

Thanks again.